# Get list called functions for a specific libary

Tags: debugging

Is there any "debugger" which lists me all functions of a dll which are getting called of a process?
I have the problem that I need to know what functions a process calls when I press a button. I tried to load it in ollydbg but it does not support x64 processes. And VisualStudio,... well I just can't find anything. So do you have any idea how I could solve that problem. I really searched a lot but I could not find a solution.

Comment: What you are looking for are profiling and code coverage tools.  Do a search for those for your platform.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a dynamic tracing toolkit for user mode Windows application, support both x86 and x64. you can check my profile page to get a download link. btw, you can operate the toolkit in the following steps:

1. run dprobe.exe
2. open `Probe` -> `Fast Probe`
3. select the process you want to trace
4. select the dll you want to trace in dll list (warning: not all dll
   export function is tracable, you can not select all for ntdll,
   kernel32, msvcrt etc system dlls, it can crash if trace some APIs.)

you can also view call statistics by `Tool` -> `Summary`, the following is snapshot of tracing firefox nspr4.dll.

[image: firefox tracing]

[image: Summary]

finally, `File` -> `Stop` to stop tracing.